Access token not working While loading llama2 model from huggingface
I requested access for llama2 models from hugging face and accepted meta license agreement. I received a mail saying access granted. But when i try to to load the model and tokenizer using access token i get the below error.

   f"{path_or_repo_id} is not a local folder and is not a valid model identifier "
   OSError: meta-llama/Llama-2-7b-chat-hf is not a local folder and is not a valid model identifier listed on 'https://huggingface.co/models'
   If this is a private repository, make sure to pass a token having permission to this repo with `use_auth_token` or log in with `huggingface-cli login` and pass `use_auth_token=True`.


here is the code that i am using for loading model and tokenizer.

    access_token = "<my-acess_token>"
    model = 'meta-llama/Llama-2-7b-chat-hf'
    
    tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained(model, use_auth_token=access_token)
    
    model = AutoModelForCausalLM.from_pretrained(
        model, 
        use_auth_token=access_token
    )


I have access to these llama2 models from hugging face. i want to load these model with out using hugging face Cli how can i do that?

first, check of the access has been properly granted. Can you see the model card and files at https://huggingface.co/meta-llama/Llama-2-7b-chat-hf ?

yes I can see them

now check if you are using a fresh, yours token, ideally create a new one and use in your code
